# Python - Standard Time to Daylight Savings Time

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that has dates referred to in Central European Standard Time (CEST, GMT+1). It is however set in standard time - meaning there's no shift to Daylight Savings Time during summer months - thus offsetting every summer month by one hour.

Is there any nifty Python module that one can correct/convert this easily with, or do I have to write manual code to do so?

Comment: Wouldn't say it's a duplicate as there's no addressing converting between standard time and DST in that question.